# Parsing and extracting data into a pandas dataframe : BeautifulSoup and XML

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

i hope you can help me with this , so i need to create a function that parse a text, and extract data into a pandas DataFrame:

"""
    Function
    ---------
    rcp_poll_data

```
Extract poll information from an XML string, and convert to a DataFrame

Parameters
----------
xml : str
    A string, containing the XML data from a page like 
    get_poll_xml(1044)

Returns
-------
A pandas DataFrame with the following columns:
    date: The date for each entry
    title_n: The data value for the gid=n graph (take the column name from the `title` tag)

This DataFrame should be sorted by date

Example
-------
Consider the following simple xml page:

<chart>
<series>
<value xid="0">1/27/2009</value>
<value xid="1">1/28/2009</value>
</series>
<graphs>
<graph gid="1" color="#000000" balloon_color="#000000" title="Approve">
<value xid="0">63.3</value>
<value xid="1">63.3</value>
</graph>
<graph gid="2" color="#FF0000" balloon_color="#FF0000" title="Disapprove">
<value xid="0">20.0</value>
<value xid="1">20.0</value>
</graph>
</graphs>
</chart>

Given this string, rcp_poll_data should return
result = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['1/27/2009', '1/28/2009']), 
                       'Approve': [63.3, 63.3], 'Disapprove': [20.0, 20.0]})
```

## Mycode

```
def rcp_poll_data(xml):
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml,'xml')
dates=soup.find("series")
datesval=soup.findChildren(string=True)
del datesval[-7:]
obama=soup.find("graph",gid="1")
obamaval={"title":obama["title"],"color":obama["color"]}
romney=soup.find("graph",gid="2")
romneyval={"title":romney["title"],"color":romney["color"]}
result = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(datesval,errors="ignore"), 'GID1':obamaval, 'GID2':romneyval})
return result
```

"""
But i keep getting this error when i execute the program :
Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Please help !
PS: the get_poll function is this :

```
def get_poll_xml(poll_id):
url="http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/"+str(poll_id)+".xml"
return requests.get(url).content
```

poll_id=1044 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) over *BeautifulSoup* (better for html web scraping) to parse XML content which has methods like `iterfind`, `findall`, `find` to XPath through child nodes, even with predicates like `@gid='1'`. And since the `<value>` elements in both `<series>` and `<graph>` parent tags are same length, you can loop in a `zip()`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

def get_poll_xml(poll_id):
    url="http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/{}.xml".format(poll_id)
    return requests.get(url).content

def rcp_poll_data(xml):

    tree = et.fromstring(xml)

    dates = []; graphlist1 = []; graphlist2 = []

    g1title = tree.find("./graphs/graph[@gid='1']").get('title')
    g2title = tree.find("./graphs/graph[@gid='2']").get('title')

    for s, g1, g2 in zip(tree.iterfind("./series/value"),
                         tree.iterfind("./graphs/graph[@gid='1']/value"),
                         tree.iterfind("./graphs/graph[@gid='2']/value")):
        dates.append(s.text)
        graphlist1.append(g1.text)
        graphlist2.append(g2.text)

    return pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(dates, errors="ignore"),
                         g1title: graphlist1,
                         g2title: graphlist2})

poll_id = 1044
xml_str = get_poll_xml(poll_id)
df = rcp_poll_data(xml_str)
```

**Output**

```
print(df.head(20))

#    Approve       Date Disapprove
# 0     63.3 2009-01-27       20.0
# 1     63.3 2009-01-28       20.0
# 2     63.5 2009-01-29       19.3
# 3     63.5 2009-01-30       19.3
# 4     61.8 2009-01-31       19.4
# 5     61.8 2009-02-01       19.4
# 6     61.8 2009-02-02       19.4
# 7     61.8 2009-02-03       19.4
# 8     61.8 2009-02-04       19.4
# 9     61.8 2009-02-05       19.4
# 10    61.6 2009-02-06       21.4
# 11    61.6 2009-02-07       21.4
# 12    61.6 2009-02-08       21.4
# 13    65.4 2009-02-09       22.6
# 14    65.4 2009-02-10       22.6
# 15    64.2 2009-02-11       23.3
# 16    64.2 2009-02-12       23.3
# 17    64.2 2009-02-13       23.3
# 18    64.8 2009-02-14       25.4
# 19    65.5 2009-02-15       25.5
```

Comment: Wow , thank you so much , i didn't know about the xml.etree.ElementTree , thanks for pointing me that out !